# intersection of two given LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

**Find the intersection of two given LinkedList (where each node has a character). 
Return the LinkedList which has character which appears in both LinkedList (same sequence order as LinkedList1).**

error:*variable temp might not have been initialized*

I tried a lot to resolve this error, but I cant step forward in this problem. Please help to resolve my error.

```
public SchNode func(SchNode head1, SchNode head2)
    {
        SchNode temp;

    for(SchNode ptr=head1;ptr!=null;ptr=ptr.nextNode)
    {
        for(SchNode ptr2=head2;ptr2!=null;ptr2=ptr2.nextNode)
        {
            if(ptr.ch==ptr2.ch)
            {
           temp.ch=ptr2.ch;
           temp=temp.nextNode;

            }
        }
    }

    return temp ;
    }
```

Comment: You have not declared temp, and you also need to initialized it .

Comment: Your question is not clear here. You are try to finding intersection of two linked list and also try to get a list which has all comman elements in sequence. Both are different things.

Comment: *"Return the LinkedList"* is confusing (bad phrasing). I read that as returning a *new* (third) LinkedList, containing the characters common to both lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method if don't understand it wrong.

- measure `list1` length, lets call it `A`
- measure `list2` length, lets call it `B`
- difference is: `C = A - B`
- if C < 0 then choose list2, else choose list1, lets call chosen list `choosenList`
- answer is `choosenList[abs(C)] //i mean absolute value of C`

EDIT: what i understand is you have two linked lists that have a common node(pointer)

Comment: This will give intersection of two linked list but not comman characters in sequence.